# Pixel perfect rendering in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, rendering

I have a 2D game in XNA which has a scrolling camera. Unfortunately, when screen is moved, I can see some artifacts - mostly blur and additional lines on the screen.

I thought about changing coordinates before drawing (approximating with `Ceiling()` or `Floor()` consistently), but this seems a little inefficient. Is this the only way?

I use `SpriteBatch` for rendering.

This is my drawing method from Camera:

`Vector2D` works on doubles, `Vector2` works on floats (used by XNA), `Srpite` is just a class with data for `spriteBatch.Draw`.

```
public void DrawSprite(Sprite toDraw)
{
    Vector2D drawingPostion;
    Vector2 drawingPos;
    drawingPostion = toDraw.Position - transform.Position;
    drawingPos.X = (float) drawingPostion.X*UnitToPixels;
    drawingPos.Y = (float) drawingPostion.Y*UnitToPixels;

    spriteBatch.Draw(toDraw.Texture, drawingPos, toDraw.Source, toDraw.Color,
        toDraw.Rotation, toDraw.Origin, toDraw.Scale, toDraw.Effects, toDraw.LayerDepth + zsortingValue);
}
```

My idea is to do this:

```
drawingPos.X = (float) Math.Floor(drawingPostion.X*UnitToPixels);
drawingPos.Y = (float) Math.Floor(drawingPostion.Y*UnitToPixels);
```

And it solves the problem. I think I can accept it this way. But are there any other options?

Comment: post some code please

Comment: Is it possible, that problems arise from me doing translation manually?

Comment: I think you might be calling DrawSprite when you wish and not when Renderer is ready. It might be in the middle of something

Comment: @tweelt This actually happens only on some positions of camera. I suppose it is when drawingPos.X and drawingPos.Y end with something close to *.5. Graphics adapter doesn't know which pixel from the texture to take.

Comment: Math.Floor is a common use then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointWrap;
```

This isn't so much a problem with your camera as it is the sampler.  Using a Point Sampler state tells the video card to take a single point color sample directly from the texture depending on the position.  Other default modes like LinearWrap and LinearClamp will interpolate between texels (pixels on your source texture) and give it a very mushy, blurred look.  If you're going for pixel-graphics, you need Point sampling.

With linear interpolation, if you have red and white next to each other in your texture, and it samples between the two (by some aspect of the camera), you will get pink.  With point sampling, you get either red or white.  Nothing in between.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't know that :)

Comment: It's great! Because you can zoom in on your textures and it will still be clearly pixelated.  Don't have to worry about directly lining up your view to the texture.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible... try something this...

```
bool redrawSprite = false;
Sprite toDraw;

void MainRenderer()
{
   if (redrawSprite)
   {
      DrawSprite(toDraw);
      redrawSprite = false;
   }
}

void ManualRefresh()
{
   "Create or set your sprite and set it to 'toDraw'"
   redrawSprite = true;
}
```

This way you will let main loop do the work like is intended.